# How can I pass two arguments to `--mail-type` option of `salloc`?

Tags: shell, slurm

I would like to pass two arguments to an option of a shell command, specifically, for `salloc`. I can choose to do either of the following

```bsh
salloc -n 1 -t 24:00:00 --mail-type=BEGIN
salloc -n 1 -t 24:00:00 --mail-type=TIME_LIMIT_80
```

where the option `mail-type` takes arguments `BEGIN`, which emails you when a node is allocated successfully, or the argument `TIME_LIMIT_80`, which  emails you when your node is approaching 80% of its time limit.

However, I would like it to do both. How can I instruct `mail-type` to take both `BEGIN` and `TIME_LIMIT_80`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I changed the title because the actual problem is specific. A general question may be asked separately; but unless it shows your research effort, it won't be a good question IMO. The answer will be short: there is no convention, it totally depends on the tool and its support.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I definitely read the manual page, that is how I learned the values `BEGIN` and `TIME_LIMIT_80`, I just totally overlooked the multiple type part. Please feel free to close the question if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the manual reads [emphasis mine]:

> ```
> --mail-type=<type>
> ```
>
> Notify user by email when certain event types occur. Valid type values are `NONE`, `BEGIN`, `END`, `FAIL`, `REQUEUE`, `ALL` (equivalent to `BEGIN`, `END`, `FAIL`, `REQUEUE`, and `STAGE_OUT`), `STAGE_OUT` (burst buffer stage out and teardown completed), `TIME_LIMIT`, `TIME_LIMIT_90` (reached 90 percent of time limit), `TIME_LIMIT_80` (reached 80 percent of time limit), and `TIME_LIMIT_50` (reached 50 percent of time limit). **Multiple type values may be specified in a comma separated list.** The user to be notified is indicated with `--mail-user`.

<sup>([source](https://slurm.schedmd.com/salloc.html))</sup>

So it seems `--mail-type=BEGIN,TIME_LIMIT_80` should work.

<sub>Note: I have never ever used `salloc`; I like reading manuals though. :)</sub>